# Finding the highest value

Tags: python, max

So I'm currently using a loop to search through my csv data to find the "high" and "low" values of a group of days and then calculate the averages of each day. With those averages, I want to find the highest one amongst them but I've been having trouble doing so. This is currently what I have.

```
for row in reversed(list(reader1)):
    openNAS, closeNAS = row['Open'], row['Close']
    highNAS, lowNAS = row['High'], row['Low']
    dateNAS = row['Date']
    averageNAS = (float(highNAS) + float(lowNAS)) / 2
    bestNAS = max(averageNAS)
```

I have indeed realized that the `max(averageNAS)` doesn't work because `averageNAS` is not a list and since the average isn't found in the csv file, I can't do `max(row['Average'])` either.

When the highest average is found, I'd also like to be able to include the date of it as well so my program can print out the date of which the highest average occurred. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I get all of your requirements, but wouldn't you put `averageNAS` in a `list` and then do `max` on that list after the `for` loop completes?

Comment: Lots of potential solutions.  Keep a variable, ```maxAVG```, and update it when you find one that is higher, also keep a variable, ```bestNAS```, and assign the entire *row* to it when you find one with an average higher than the max.

Comment: @tdelaney
Could you write a quick example of the code? I'm a real novice when it comes to coding right now and I learn by looking at examples and explanations of why it works or why it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a dictionary of average values where the date is the key and the average is the value:

```
averageNAS = {}
```

Then calculate the average and insert it into this dict:

```
for row in reversed(list(reader1)):
    highNAS, lowNAS = row['High'], row['Low']
    dateNAS = row['Date']
    averageNAS[dateNAS] = (float(highNAS) + float(lowNAS)) / 2 # Insertion
```

Now you can get the maximum by finding the highest value:

```
import operator
bestNAS = max(averageNAS.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

The result will be a tuple like:

```
# (1, 8.0)
```

which means that day 1 had the highest average. And the average was 8.

If you don't need the day then you could create a list instead of a dictionary and append to it. That makes finding the maximum a bit easier:

```
averageNAS = []
for ...
    averageNAS.append((float(highNAS) + float(lowNAS)) / 2)
bestNAS = max(averageNAS)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions that come to mind.

## Solution 1

The method most similar to your existing solution would be to create a list of the averages as you calculate them, and then take the maximum from that list. The code, based on your example, looks something like this:

```
averageNAS = []
for row in reversed(list(reader1)):
    openNAS, closeNAS = row['Open'], row['Close']
    highNAS, lowNAS = row['High'], row['Low']
    dateNAS = row['Date']
    averageNAS.append((float(highNAS) + float(lowNAS)) / 2)

# the maximum of the list only needs to be done once (at the end)
bestNAS = max(averageNAS)
```

## Solution 2

Instead of creating an entire list, you could just maintain a variable of the maximum average NAS that you've "seen" so far, and the dateNAS associated with it. That would look something like:

```
bestNAS = float('-inf')
bestNASdate = None
for row in reversed(list(reader1)):
    openNAS, closeNAS = row['Open'], row['Close']
    highNAS, lowNAS = row['High'], row['Low']
    dateNAS = row['Date']
    averageNAS = (float(highNAS) + float(lowNAS)) / 2
    if averageNAS > bestNAS:
        bestNAS = averageNAS
        bestNASdate = dateNAS
```

## Solution 3

If you want to use a package as a solution, I'm fairly certain that the **pandas** package can do this easily and efficiently. I'm not 100% certain that the pandas syntax is exact, but the library has everything that you'd need to get this done. It's based on numpy, so the operations are faster/more efficient than a vanilla python loop.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'file location')
df['averageNAS'] = df[["High", "Low"]].mean(axis=1)
bestNASindex = df['averageNAS'].argmax() # 90% sure this is the right syntax
bestNAS = df['averageNAS'][bestNASindex]
bestNASdate = df['date'][bestNASindex]
```

Comment: In your first solution finding the maximum can be done after the `for`-loop instead of inside it.

Comment: @MSeifert I was trying to make the first solution a minimal change from the code in the question, but I agree, it makes sense to just do it outside the loop.